# Style selector, keep style between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a webpage, i made a style selector, but when i access other page of my webpage, the style I selected, disappears.

I have something like this.

```js
function setStyleSheet(url) {
                var stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");
                stylesheet.setAttribute('href', url);
            }
```

```css
html {
    height: 1000px;
}

body {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


#navbar {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}

.css_switch a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li class="css_switch"><a class="dark" onclick="setStyleSheet('dark.css')" href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li class="css_switch"><a class="light" onclick="setStyleSheet('light.css')" href="#">Light</a></li>
    </ul>   
    <div>
        CONTENT TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want to do, is that if you switched to style named "Dark", when default is "Light", and you switch to other .html, the new .html has the style "Dark"

Comment: Why create a new stylesheet. Why not give body a class such as .dark or .light and in CSS file you can create the dark theme style by referencing body class as the parent. For example .dark div {background-color: black;} and .light div {background-color: white;}. To change the style use JavaScript to change the class of the body element to either .light or .dark

Comment: @IPAddress Because then you have to load a stylesheet that contains both themes in it. The load time would get worse and worse as more themes were added. It would get really slow if there where 10s or 100s of different themes.

Comment: @4castle Your point is valid. However, you did mention dark or light theme only in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the user's choice either locally, or server side. Locally you can store information in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or cookies. Server side you can store the information in a database or a session variable.

The easiest to implement imo would be localStorage. Modify your `setStyleSheet` function to store the user's choice. And then add a onload event that will execute as soon as the page loads, retrieve that choice from localStorage, and then set the style sheet to the selected url.

```
//onload event to set the style 
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   var templateUrl = localStorage.cssTemplate || "light.css";
   document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttribute("href",templateUrl);
});

function setStyleSheet(url) {
    var stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");
    stylesheet.setAttribute('href', url);
    localStorage.cssTemplate = url;
}
```

You could also instead of using files use a class to manipulate the overall template. For instance have a `body.light` and `body.dark` classes. Then add rules using those as prefixes

```
body.light div { background:white; }
body.light nav { background:#EFEFEF; }

body.dark div { background:black; }
body.dark nav { background:#1E1E1E; }
```

Then instead of setting a file url, simply change the class on the body element

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   var template = localStorage.cssTemplate || "light";
   document.body.className = template;
});

function setStyleSheet(template) {
    document.body.className = template;
    localStorage.cssTemplate = template;
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfect! That was what i want, thaks for your reply and your help.

Comment: Yesterday your code was working great, now i changed the file system on my localhost. If i have a directory tree like:   /root/index.html        /root/style/main.css        /root/style/light.css        /root/style/dark.css        /root/page1/index.html        /root/page2/index.html          I have to change your code? Because now is not working. If I'm on Page1 and i choose the style2, i go to page2 and I have de default style, if i go back to page1 i have style2 again

Comment: @SergiFernàndez It depends on how you implemented it. Can you give a JSFiddle or similar to show how you implemented it? But all you should have to change is the part: `|| "light.css"` which just needs changed to the path of whatever is your default css file.

Comment: Because you are using a relative path for your files. You have `style/light.css` on your main page and `../style/light.css` on the others. When saving from the main page and going to a subpage its going to try to get the style at like `/testing/style/light.css`. Either use an absolute path or a path starting with / on all pages, ie `/style/light.css`

Comment: Now I made changes, but it half works, sorry for my english. Now if i picked dark style and i switch pages, all pages has de dark style, but it seems like theres no light style as default, because at the start there's no green background in the style switcher . I hope you can see what i say here: http://i.imgur.com/4B0RSGe.gifv    Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because you are still using a relative path `style/light.css`,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you lose all the data in the html document when you navigate to other page. To keep it, you could pass the last selected style as a parameter in the url, or you could save it in a cookie, or even in a http session if you are using a server capable of keeping sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm interested in the firt option, Pass the selecte style as a parameter in the URL, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie in the browser:

```
document.cookie = "theme=" + url + "; expires=" + 
                  new Date(Date.now()+365*24*60*60*1000).toUTCString();
```

And then every time a page loads, get the theme:

```
var theme = ((document.cookie || "").match(/theme=(\w+)/) || ["","light"])[1];
document.getElementById("stylesheet").href = theme + ".css";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i never used cookies, so i don't know where to write that code.

Comment: The top code goes in your `setStylesheet` method, and the bottom code goes in an `onload` block. I already wrote all the code you'll need.